# R subset dataframe where no observations of certain variables

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping, subset, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe that looks like

| country | sector | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| France | 1 | 7 | . |
| France | 2 | 10 | . |
| belgium | 1 | 12 | 7 |
| belgium | 2 | 14 | 8 |

I want to subset columns that are missing for a country in all sectors. In this example I would like to drop/exclude column two because it is missing for sector 1 and 2 for france. To be clear I would also be throwing out the values of data2 for belgium in this example.

My expected output would look like

| country | sector | data1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| France | 1 | 7 |
| France | 2 | 10 |
| belgium | 1 | 12 |
| belgium | 2 | 14 |

data 2 is now excluded because it had a complete set of missing values for all sectors in France

Comment: Hi expected outputs are added, sorry! Missing values are NA

Comment: IN the expecteed, i think the column names are switched

Comment: You are correct, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may group by country, create logical columns where the count of `NA` elements are equal to group size, ungroup, replace the corresponding columns to NA based on the logical column and remove those columns in `select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.x)) == n(),
       .names = "{.col}_lgl")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  mutate(across(names(df1)[-1], ~ if(any(get(str_c(cur_column(), 
     "_lgl")) )) NA else .x)) %>% 
   select(c(where(~ !is.logical(.x) && any(complete.cases(.x)))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  country sector data1
  <chr>    <int> <int>
1 France       1     7
2 France       2    10
3 belgium      1    12
4 belgium      2    14
```

---

If we don't use group_by, the steps can be simplified as showed in `Maël's` post i.e. do the grouping with a base R function within `select` i.e. either `tapply` or `ave` can work

```
df1 %>%
   select(where(~ !any(tapply(is.na(.x), df1[["country"]], 
     FUN = all))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("France", "France", "belgium", "belgium"
), sector = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), data1 = c(7L, 10L, NA, 14L), data2 = c(NA, 
NA, 7L, 8L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but this will drop data2 because there is *any* NA in it. I need to drop it because it's NA for *all* observations of country. So I can keep where one is missing but not all.

Comment: @StephenB Not clear about the actual case.  Maybe the update helps?

Comment: Yes this seems to have done it! I guess the example wasn't super clear as I was trying to keep it parsimonious. I should have had a third column where only one value was NA but I would still keep that. So your code drops where there is a complete case of missing values within the group country.

Comment: @StephenB i added a NA in data1 for testing

Comment: On a sidenote, I was expecting `where` to be applied by group after a `group_by` call, which is not the case. Maybe that needs to be issued somewhere!

Comment: @Maël the issue is that it is a grouping step and `select` is selecting the columns, maybe we don't need to grouping, but use `ave` in `select` (as in your code), thus it can work

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "country   sector  data1   data2
France  1   7   NA
France  2   10  2
belgium 1   12  7
belgium 2   14  8")
df2 <- read.table(header = T, text = "country   sector  data1   data2
France  1   7   NA
France  2   10  NA
belgium 1   12  7
belgium 2   14  8")

df1[!sapply(df1, \(x) any(ave(x, df1$country, FUN = \(y) all(is.na(y)))))]

#   country sector data1 data2
# 1  France      1     7    NA
# 2  France      2    10     2
# 3 belgium      1    12     7
# 4 belgium      2    14     8

df2[!sapply(df2, \(x) any(ave(x, df2$country, FUN = \(y) all(is.na(y)))))]
#   country sector data1
# 1  France      1     7
# 2  France      2    10
# 3 belgium      1    12
# 4 belgium      2    14
```

Note: `\` replaces `function`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this will drop data2 because there is any NA in it. I need to drop it because it's NA for all observations of country. So I can keep where one is missing but not all

Answer (score 2):

For a base R solution, you can use the apply family on column names and detect if there's any NA in the values of all columns:

```
keep_remove <- sapply(names(data), \(x) all(!is.na(data[[x]]))) 
data <- data[, keep_remove]
```